# Client Server architecture on localhost per-user

Tags: http, client-server, named-pipes

I'm currently designing a system that will consist of a single server process and multiple client processes. The server and all clients will run on the same machine in the same login session. These processes will talk to each other via plain HTTP.
Other users should not be able to interfer with or listen in on this communication. The design should be easily portable between Windows and *nix systems.

When a user opens a TCP port and listens on the loopback-interface only, other users logged in on the same machine can still connect to this port.
While HTTP usually uses TCP as its transport layer anything providing reliable and ordered stream delivery should work. So to ensure communication remains restricted to a single user switching to named pipes seems like a good idea. However the semantics of named pipes differ quite substantially between Windows (duplex, single name for and receiving ends) and POSIX (simplex, separate names for and receiving ends). Also, most existing HTTP implementations do not support using something other than TCP for transport.

Is there some other portable per-user inter-process stream delivery method I'm missing? Or can I perhaps somehow make TCP ports accessible only to specific users?

Answer (score 0):

In teory, the only thing that matters it the protocol. You could use any protocol and it would work on any system, as far as you use the same protocol for client and servers.

Depending on your tecnology you may have a lot of propocols libs available, like in java.

Comment: Well, the application protocol is not really the question in my case. I know I want to use HTTP. It's just that I might need a non-standard transport layer _below_ the protocol to ensure user isolation.